# How to map existing table with EF 5 Code First and _do_ not create/touch it when running update-database?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have an EF 5 Code First VS 2012 project and some entites. I use update-database to generate/seed the tables and data. However I have 4 existing tables with data, and I would like to map this tables to 4 POCO class, because I would like to access them via DbContext.

My problem if I create the entity POCO classes, and add the approprite

```
public DbSet<MyExternal> MyExternals { get; set; }
```

property to my DbContext class, when I run the update-database it tries to create the tables and exits with error "Table  MyExternal is exists" or similar. I understand why is that, but my question: 
How to explain to the update-database process to not create/alter these tables?

Note: I know how to map tables to different names than class name etc, not this is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is rather old and probably answered by yourself, but the solution might be to create an empty migration:

```
public override void Up()
{
}

public override void Down()
{
}
```

Afterwards your Migration has stored the correct database model (in which your four tables are known) and everything should work out just fine